# Closed questions come back to haunt me when they are edited

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, interesting-page

Something surprising happened with this question today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896776/please-help-me-convert-this-c-code-to-python

Four days ago, I (and others) closed this question (as too broad).  Then recently the OP came back and [added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27896776/revisions) a couple sentences to the question (which do not really change anything).  This brought the question back to the top of my "Interesting" tab (which is my default view on SO).

The problem is, the question did not become interesting at all.  It was a poor question four days ago, and I'm not sure I'd find it interesting even if it were significantly rewritten.  But especially **since the question remains closed and down-voted, does it really deserve my attention again?**

Since several days had passed, I had actually forgotten the title and author of the question, so was "tricked" into spending time reading it all over again--only to find out it was closed by myself.  This felt pretty strange, from a UX point of view.

Comment: Hey cool, someone downvoted this within a couple minutes of my posting it, with no comment or vote to close.  Have I offended?

Comment: The idea is that a closed question might be amenable to editing to improve it to an answerable state. An edit bumps it to the Reopen Review Queue, and apparently to the Interesting tab as well. I definitely agree that the latter -- without the question having been reopened -- doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "*I'm not sure I'd find it interesting even if it were significantly rewritten*" Really? Wow.

Comment: @Tom When edited, it will be send into the Reopen review queue, where people can vote for it to be reopened. If John would visit the reopen review queue in that time frame, the question definetly would be presented to him to vote on it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. This will happen automatically? interesting, I didn't knew that. Thank you for that information.

Comment: @Tom Yes, it won't take long until you can review them.

Comment: @Jeroen: If a question is fundamentally unanswerable, off-topic, trivial or otherwise of no value to a site, all the rewrites in the world won't make it interesting. (I suppose  this line might be baiting downvotes.)

Comment: @Lilienthal In the post OP speaks of "poor question", not of "fundamentally unanswerable question", so your comment is a bit of a straw man argument.

Comment: Don't worry, it has been deleted now and you have probably put of the OP from posting here ever again.

Comment: @Jeroen: Your argument, if you want to call it that, was feigned outrage at the idea that someone could consider any question to be unsalvageable. I suggested a few cases, out of many, where a question is at its core unsuitable for the site and hence unredeemable. If you want to continue the logic games: I wanted to counter your appeal to emotion that all questions are worth saving by stating that at least some questions are not.